# Files for which to activate generic mode

Tags: regular-expressions, major-mode

I've created a generic mode for emacs, but I have trouble matching the file names I want the generic mode to be on, right now I'm using `proguard-*` but I would like to match only file names with `proguard-*.txt` and `proguard-*.pro`. How can I do this?

Comment: Show your code for how you're currently matching filenames, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for selecting a major mode are a bit complex, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes) says this about choosing based on the file name :

> Fourth—if Emacs still hasn’t found a suitable major mode—it looks at
>   the file’s name.  The correspondence between file names and major modes
>   is controlled by the variable ‘auto-mode-alist’.  Its value is a list in
>   which each element has this form,
>
> ```
> (REGEXP . MODE-FUNCTION)
> ```
>
> or this form,
>
> ```
> (REGEXP MODE-FUNCTION FLAG)
> ```

What it doesn't say explicitely (nor the docstring for `auto-mode-alist`) is that what is matched against the regexp is the **full pathname** of the file.

The syntax of [regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) is also decribed in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that something like this should do what you want?

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("^proguard-.*\\.txt$" . generic-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("^proguard-.*\\.pro$" . generic-mode))
```

Replace `generic-mode` by the actual name of your mode, of course.

The strings are regular expressions, or regexps for short. You may read about them in the elisp manual.

Comment: Specifically, Elisp manual, node [Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html) and its subnodes.